# How can Select arrays from associate array in php on the basis on element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$arrItems['items']` in which 5 more arrays (associate array) and each array contain 5 element (with the keys: `f_name, l_name, contact, address, seller_id`).

I want to get all those arrays (from `$arrItems['items']`) in which element of `seller_id` is 1 like `"seller_id"=>1` Code given below.

Please guide me how use foreach loop or else...

```
array(5)
{
  [0] =>
    array(5)
    {
      ["f_name"] =>
        string(3) "abc"
      ["l_name"] =>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["contact"] =>
        string(5) "12345"
      ["address"] =>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["seller_id"] =>
        string(1) => "1"
    }
  [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["f_name"]=>
        string(3) "abc"
      ["l_name"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["contact"]=>
        string(5) "12345"
      ["address"]=>
        string(3) "xyz"
      ["seller_id"]=>
        string(1)=>"1"
}
[2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"5"
}
[3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"1"
}
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["f_name"]=>
      string(3) "abc"
    ["l_name"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["contact"]=>
      string(5) "12345"
    ["address"]=>
      string(3) "xyz"
    ["seller_id"]=>
      string(1)=>"1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find simple solution using foreach.

```
$arr = [];
foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $i => $row) {
    if ($row['seller_id'] != 1) {
        // Ignore row if seller_id is not 1
        continue;
    }

    // here you got only elements with seller_id = 1
    // so you can add them to a new array
    $arr[] = $row;
}

// After the loop (foreach) in $row you get only elements with seller_id 1.
// If they must be in $arrItems['items'] use it
$arrItems['items'] = $arr;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrItems['items']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [f_name] => abc
    [l_name] => xyz
    [contact] => 12345
    [address] => xyz
    [seller_id] => 1
)
```

Comment: Yes It Work ! Thanks medskill

Comment: I think the other answers are also good or maybe better than mine (because they have a shorter code).

Comment: it Filter right But an error occur  **must be of the type array, string given**  

when i assign  $arrItems['items']=$row

Comment: $row is only one row in loop, if you want to assign all items to a array, check the other answers, they have a better answer.

Comment: I have just edited my answer to resolve your issue, you can try my code again. Anyway the other answers (from Jannis, Kamal Paliwal and dWinder) are also good and shorter than this.

Comment: Yes @medskil it work Perfect. Thank you

Comment: !   actually i use this  array for order. if 1 order contain 3 seller_id Like seller_id=>1,2,3 mean in this order the items that contains belong to 3 seller stores.
if   "seller_id" => 1 or "seller_id"=>1,2,3 then above algorithm Perfect But if seller id  like  "seller_id"=> 3,2,1 then this algorithm fail to filter.
Kindly guid me little more how can filter that arrays also in which id 1 is exist.

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand you, you want to get $arrItems with "seller_id" value "3,2,1" ? Or do you want to sort your array in descending order.

Comment: medskill i want $arritems with "seller_id"=>"3,2,1" 
I did this by edit your code.





`$seller_order_arr = [];
        foreach ($arrItems['items'] as  $row) {
            if (strpos($row['current_seller_id'] ,",") > 1 && $row['current_seller_id'] != null){
                $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
            }
            if($row['current_seller_id'] == 1){
                $seller_order_arr[] = $row;
            }
        }
        $arrItems['items'] = $seller_order_arr;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

> array_filter — Filters elements of an array using a callback function

In your case:

```
$sellerId = "1";
$arr = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($e) use ($sellerId) {
    return $sellerId == $e["seller_id"]; });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($arrItems['items'] as $subarray) {
    if ($subarray[seller_id] === 1) {
        $result[] = $subarray;
    }
}
```

is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_filter` to filter the items of array

```
$arr = array_filter($arrItems['items'], function($arr) {
    return $e["seller_id"] == 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplest way to get it just two line of code.

```
$key = array_search(1, array_column($arrayItems, 'seller_id'));

print_r($arrayItems[$key]);
```

This method use binary search technics, when number 100000303 foreach loop will take a lot of time to finished it.

Comment: **$userdb** mean ?

Comment: @HaFizUmer i've changed it. look

Comment: No am sorry this solution is not Perfect for my problem. You solution just return "int(1)" mean it filter right But just return total no of array in which "seller)id"=> 1.
I value of arrays also.
So @medskill answer Perfect here.
Thank you for response me.